# Насколько большая должна быть разница между вопросами, чтоб система не считала их дубликатами?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, дубликаты

Недавно создал два вопроса и сам же на них ответил (исходя из ["делитесь знаниями в стиле вопросов и ответов"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)):

- [Как получить значение свойства объекта по его адресу?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1034806)
- [Как получить тип значения свойства объекта по его адресу?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1034820)

Причиной создания, было отсутствие подобных ответов/вопросов на ruSO (по крайней мере я не нашёл). Уже при создании вопросов система определяла эти два вопросы как дубликаты, хотя и в заголовках, и в решении имеются различия.

Являются ли указанные вопросы дубликатами и если "да" - то почему? По каким критериям система определяет разные вопросы дубликатами?

Comment: Достаточной, чтобы убедить составляющих эту "систему" - т.е. нас, пользователей с правами закрытия/открытия вопросов. Если серьезно, вопросы довольно похожи и сводятся к "как программно обратится к свойству по адресу", выглядит как дубликат.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight т.е., Ваше мнение, что нужно эти два вопроса объединить в один "Как программно обратиться к свойству объекта по адресу"?

Comment: @XelaNimed, нет никакой системы, есть пользователи, которые вручную могут отметить (или не отметить) вопрос как дубликат. Или проголосовать за переоткрытие вопроса. Все субъективно.

Comment: Объединяются только точные дубликаты (например, созданные по ошибке). Если формулировка отличается, можно просто оставить все как есть, нет ничего плохого в некотором количестве дубликатов. Нет смысла пытаться добиться совершенства.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight т.е. я могу убрать из заголовка вопроса "[дубликат]"?

Comment: @XelaNimed, нет, не можете. Текст `[дубликат]` исчезнет сам, если вопрос будет переоткрыт (после того как за его переоткрытие проголосует достаточное количество участников). Мое мнение - можно было задать один вопрос про получение типа и значения. Но в принципе можно и так.

Comment: Ваши два вопроса являются полными дубликатами. Вы используете одни и те же данные, одну и туже методику, отличие только, это в одном вы достаете значение, а в другом тип. Давайте создадим штук 100 вопросов, где мы при помощи рефлексии будем что то еще доставать, думаете это правильно? Если вы хотите сделать такой вопрос-ответ, то он должен быть универсальный, объяснять саму методику, что бы каждый мог прочитать, понять и переделать под себя. К примеру есть [такой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420354) вопрос, который лишь показал как можно и он стал "закрывашкой" для многих вопросов по HTML.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ большое спасибо за Ваше пояснение. На будущее буду знать, в особенности когда буду отвечать по JS.