# До какой степени можно исправлять вопросы?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, правки, закрытие-вопросов

По конкретной [дискуссии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9774/195342). По поводу [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1046773/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80), который привычно звучит как "Написать функцию..." и далее по тексту.

По ходу дела вышел на [совет](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/552/195342) - исправить вопрос так, чтобы он не вызывал такого раздражения.

Да я и сам написал было о вопросе - мол, если бы автор вопроса написал *"какие есть способы по координатам трех вершин треугольника определить его площадь"* - то это был бы совсем другой, и даже интересный вопрос.

Но встает другой вопрос - по сути, такое изменение меняет сам вопрос. И, соответственно, вопрос (брр... сплошные вопросы) - как определить допустимую меру внесения изменений?

В этом конкретном случае автор хотел конкретный код, а не обсуждение вопроса о поиске площади? Это же - совсем другое? но сам вопрос мог бы быть спасен.

Спасать ли вопросы такой ценой или лучше просто закрывать, как вы думаете?

Comment: Никто не запрещает создать свой вопрос в любом виде, начав его со ссылки и вводной фразы "по мотивам вопроса линк у меня родился вот какой вопрос". Возможно люди и туда и туда подтянутся, а уж что решит наша "[система детектирования дубликатов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9640/213987)" это в общем случае вопрос слишком неконкретный.

Comment: @AK Это получится, что я создаю вопрос, на который сам же и отвечаю :) Не люблю я такие вопросы - ответы...

Comment: Почему не любите? ("Вы так говорите, как будто это что-то плохое") Правилами so самоответы не запрещаются, а поощряются. Считайте, что ведёте некоторый блог: если вы будете постить интересные и правильные вещи, то вас будут читать и лайкать, иногда вам будут подкидывать ещё более интересные варианты, которые вы не заметили.

Comment: @AK я тоже не большой поклонник подобных само-ответов (:

Comment: @AK Ну... не знаю, но как только я такое пишу, налетает такая волна критики, что я, как правило, в результате такие вопросы удаляю :) И вообще - ну разве мы знаем, почему любим или не любим то или иное?...

Answer (score 2):

Частично смежные обсуждения:

- [Неужели правки, противоречащие намерениям автора, бывают допустимы?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6181/15479)
- [Стоит ли насильно редактировать вопрос, если половина оного в комментариях](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2134/15479).

По сабжу же...

Подобная правка подпадает под пункт о "противоречии с намерениями автора":

> Правка не соответствует исходному содержанию сообщения. Даже правки, которые призваны изменить сообщение в корне, должны быть выполнены с соблюдением идей автора сообщения.

Далее:

> В этом конкретном случае автор хотел конкретный код

Не совсем. Автор хотел решения проблемы. Вот только я не берусь сказать, в чём у него проблема.

Он может не знать формулу, тогда в ответе было бы достаточно лишь математики или псевдокода. Но, вполне возможно, что он не знает, как написать функции (правда, слабо себе такое представляю).

Для меня это видится так, будто автор не приложил абсолютно никаких усилий к пониманию своей собственной же задачи и просто привёл задание от преподавателя.

Такие вопросы, насколько я помню, решили минусовать.

Comment: Не вы ли сами навели меня на дискуссию, где был вариант ответа - исправлять :) А если удалять - [верните отобранный пункт на место](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9774/195342) :)

Comment: @Harry если я даю ссылки на обсуждения, это не значит, что я полностью согласен с их тезисами. И уж точно я не навязываю их. Каждый сам делает выводы. Но если у нас получится прийти к полному консенсусу с сообществом по этому вопросы, было бы хорошо)

Comment: @Harry по поводу же удаления. Минусовать и потом голосовать за удаление - лучше, чем просто закрывать. По-моему, PP на это упирал при обсуждении отключения причины закрытия.

Comment: Когда - "потом"? Я, например, крайне редко обращаюсь к старым вопросам, если только не приходит "именной" комментарий. Так что я просто высказываю свое "пфе" и больше никогда к такому вопросу не возвращаюсь... Кстати, иногда это даже плохо - вдруг вопрос будет исправлен так, что станет приличным? :) Интересно, кстати, что как дубль вопрос можно закрыть сразу, одним "золотом", а тут - нет. А вообще я сейчас одну крамольную мысль выскажу... У нас уже такая база вопросов, что, похоже, по ней уже никто и не пытается поиск вести, если что - так, в лучшем случае, если при указании темы что выскочит.

Comment: @Harry "никто и не пытается поиск вести". Вы про тех, кто задаёт вопросы? Не думаю, что дело в размере базы. Авторы вопросов очень часто в принципе поиском не любят пользоваться.

Comment: И это тоже есть...